# нужна помощь в составлении\исправлении скрипта

Tags: python, linux

Прошу помощи в написании скрипта или исправлении того что сам написал (ps не работает).
Суть такая, имеется файл, на скриншоте справа, в нем нужно изменить строчку backup_source, но после знака =, менять ее должен пользователь (как я понимаю по средствам input).
Буду благодарен оказаной помощи, если не трудно опишите пожалуйста что должен делать Ваш скрипт или как исправить мои)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
path = '/home/artem/.synbak/rsync/test.conf'
name1 = 'backup_source'  # имя параметра
value1 = input('what you want backup:')  # то что задает пользователь


def set_option(name1, value1):
    with open(path) as f:
        current_config = f.read().splitlines()
    for i, option in enumerate(current_config):
        if option.strip().startswith(name1 + '='):
            current_config[i] = '%s=%s' % (name1, value1)
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(current_config))
        f.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Замените изображение текстом.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вставил текст кода

Comment: `name1 = input("backup source: ")  # имя параметра`

Comment: @gil9red Сейчас доберусь до дома, попробую)

Comment: @gil9red изменение на ввод нечего не дало к сожалению

Comment: Почему не дало? Теперь у вас спрашивает значение. А то, что у вас там просто функция set_option, которая не вызывается, это другой вопрос. Напишите в конце файла после описания функции: `set_option(name1, value1)`

Comment: @gil9red да я уже починил =) спасибо за подсказку)

Comment: @ArtemMazur, проблема, описанная в вопросе решена? :)

Comment: @gil9red да) теперь думаю как сделать проверку на то, имеется ли такая папка которую указываю в backup_source вообще на диске)